# JFrame content area size wrong after pack and visible

Tags: java, windows-7, size, frame

I think there is a bug in Java's calculation of the total size of a window, where it adds the top and right border values a second time to the overall window size. 
I apologize if this is a known problem, but I didn't find it in all of the volume of material.

I have this problem with the latest java 7 21 (using Netbeans 7.3).
I am trying to create a window with a content area exactly 1024x768 (on a larger monitor) to emulate full screen of a 1024x768 monitor in a window for game development.
I just create a frame and draw a 1024x768 black rectangle into the window.

The content area is too large by exactly the height of the title bar (top border insets value) and the width by the size of the right hand border.  This jumped out at me since the right border is right next to a stripe exactly the same width.

In debug, the insets after pack()/setVisible(true) are 30 top, 8 sides and bottom.
There is a 30 pixel white strip inside of the bottom of the window border below the black rectangle, and to the right there is an 8 pixel border.

I tried using a content pane JPanel into the window with exactly the same results adding it to BorderLayout.CENTER.

This should be correct and isn't:
    setPreferredSize(contentDim.width + insets.left + insets.right,
                     contentDim.height + insets.top + insets.bottom);
This works and shouldn't: 
    setPreferredSize(contentDim.width + insets.left,
                     contentDim.height + insets.bottom);

Here's the full code.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package jframesizebug;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author liblabs-guest
 */
public class JFrameBug extends JFrame {

    public JFrameBug() {
        setTitle("JFrameSizeBug");
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        pack();
        Insets insets = getInsets();
        contentDim = new Dimension(500,400);
        /*
         * This SHOULD be correct to the pixel, but it creates a window 
         * that is too big vertically by the top inset, and horizontally
         * by the right inset.  
         * When run there is a white strip along the bottom of the content area
         * inside the outer border that is the same size as the title bar at 
         * the top of the window.  Also there is a white stripe inside the 
         * right border of the content area the same width as the outer border.
         */
        windowDim = new Dimension(
                contentDim.width + insets.left + insets.right,
                contentDim.height + insets.top + insets.bottom);
        /*
         * This works and shouldn't
        windowDim = new Dimension(
                contentDim.width + insets.right,
                contentDim.height + insets.bottom);
        */
        /*
         * This shows the problem with a white border of 2 pixels at the 
         * bottom and right. 
        windowDim = new Dimension(
                contentDim.width + insets.right,
                contentDim.height + insets.bottom);
        */
        setSize(windowDim);
        setPreferredSize(windowDim);
        setMinimumSize(windowDim);
        setMaximumSize(windowDim);
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrameBug frame = new JFrameBug();
                frame.renderLoop();
            }
        });
    }        
    private void renderLoop() {
        setVisible(true);
        createBufferStrategy(1);
        bufferStrategy = getBufferStrategy();
        g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
        if (!bufferStrategy.contentsLost()) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0,0,contentDim.width, contentDim.height);
            bufferStrategy.show();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JFrameBug.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;
    private Dimension contentDim;
    private Dimension windowDim;
    private Graphics g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a window with a content area exactly 1024x768

Use an undecorated JFrame so you don't see the title bar and borders.

Or if you want to see the title bar and border then use:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Then when you add your panel to the content pane is will be sized to fill the space left over taking into account the title and borders.